# How to authenticate a Firewall web page via Powershell / Selenium-Chrome Driver?

Tags: powershell, selenium, batch-file, selenium-webdriver, vbscript

I developed several scripts in Powershell to automate the configuration of machines where I work, streamlining and avoiding the hard work of manually configuring a huge amount of stations. Basically they use disable UAC, autologon, and Task Scheduler.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkuDl.png

The biggest problem is the use of the Fortinet Firewall that asks for authentication via browser, since much of the application uses files for installation that are on the server via SMB, it is necessary to do this authentication, because without it it is not possible for the algorithm to authenticate to the server, causing it to fail on the course.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqZAR.png

Page URL: https://authenticator.mpms.mp.br/caplogin/?login&post=http://10.111.147.1:1000/fgtauth&magic=0202e294cb1c7073&usermac=10:e7:c6:c5:c3:61&apmac=00:00:00:00:00:00&apip=10.111.147.1&userip=10.111.147.22&ssid=PGJ-BANCADA&apname=FGT2KE3917900027&bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00&device_type=windows-pc

However, by testing this through Selenium it even authenticates, but after the computer restarts and runs the next script, it asks for authentication again.

Follow the code that I made to authenticate in Fortnet, followed after the login, to make a request in the globo.com site

```
############################################
######## Enable Fortinet Firewall ##########
############################################

$YourURL = "https://authenticator.mpms.mp.br/"

# Adds the path for ChromeDriver.exe to the environmental variable 
$env:PATH += ";C:\Util\PSL\" 

# Adding Selenium's .NET assembly (dll) to access it's classes in this PowerShell session
Add-Type -Path "C:\Util\PSL\WebDriver.dll" 

$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)
$ChromeDriver.Capabilities.BrowserName

# Browse to the specified website
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($YourURL) 

# Methods to find the input textbox for google search and then to type something in it
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByName("username").SendKeys("username")
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys("password") 
$ChromeDriver.FindElementsByClassName("submit").Submit() 


#### New page #####
$YourURL = "https://www.globo.com/"
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($YourURL) 

Function Stop-ChromeDriver {Get-Process -Name chromedriver -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}

# Close selenium browser session method
$ChromeDriver.Close() 

# End ChromeDriver process method
$ChromeDriver.Quit() 

# Function to make double sure the Chromedriver process is finito (double-tap!)
Stop-ChromeDriver
```

When we do this manually, the next steps will run normally, which by my conclusion makes the Selenium driver not really the Google Chrome browser, but rather its own one, which means that it does not recognize authentication. .

The question that remains is: Is it possible to add this option in the script so that we can authenticate to Fortinet Web and thus avoid manual steps and automate our work? I wish I could perform this task for Powershell, but I'm available with another alternative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use **vbs** in **PowerShell`** to send **required authorizations**?

````ps1
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $obj = New-Object -com Wscript.Shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Chrome');
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 300 >$null
$obj.SendKeys('paulogoncalves');
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 150 >$null
$obj.SendKeys("{TAB}")
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 150 >$null
$obj.SendKeys('senhasecreta')
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 150 >$null
$obj.SendKeys('{ENTER}');```
````